# Nested Tables, how to stop jquery event firing IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

Suppose I have a nested table like the following:

```
<table id="search">
<tbody>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>
       <table>
           <tr id="ex"><td>-----------</td></tr>           
        </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
       </tbody>
```

I want to bind a click event to the rows which are not in the nested table (so not to the row with ID "ex"). To clarify, I do not want anything at all to occur when I click on the excluded row. This seems like it should be easy, but I am having trouble with IE propagating events (I think).

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9TWPx/1/

Here's what I've tried:

Base Case: Default behavior)

```
$("#search tr").click(function() {
alert($(this).closest("tr").index()); 
});
```

When clicking on the last row, this causes TWO alerts - firstly one containing the index 0, and then one containing the index 2.

Attempt #1)

```
$("#search tr").not("#ex").click(function() {
alert($(this).closest("tr").index());
});
```

This doesn't work - I no longer get the alert containing the 0 index, but I still get the alert containing the index 2 - which indicates to me that something must be bubbling up to the parent level (right?)

event.stopPropagation() doesn't seem to help -
Attempt #2)

```
$("#search tr").not("#ex").click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();   
alert($(this).closest("tr").index());    
});
```

This causes me to get an alert with the index 2.

Attempt #3+)

I tried many different combinations of `preventDefault()`, `stopBubble`, `stopPropogation` etc and nothing seems to stop me from getting the alert with the index 2.

I realize this may have a simple answer, but please share it with me if you know!

Final edit: Turns out that this has nothing to do with event propagation, just to do with the fact that I missed that the row containing the nested table itself was getting the event bound to it, as well as the row inside the nested table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$("#search > tbody > tr:not(:has('table'))").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").index());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9TWPx/9/)

Comment: You still get index 2 with this, the OP is looking not to return that.

Comment: This is still causing an alert to be triggered when clicking on the last row - I should have added that I did try that.

Comment: I answered that because of this line "I want to bind a click event to the rows which are not in the nested table" I did't really understood if he wanted the 0 or the index of the tr of the #search table

Comment: So the alert must be only on the first and second row?

Comment: That's correct, sorry for the lack of clarity in my OP.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I see my error now, I didn't consider that I needed to not bind the row containing the table, as well as the row inside the table. Not enough coffee, maybe. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated code -

```
$('#search tr').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ( this.id != "ex" ) {
        alert($(this).closest("tr").index());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/9TWPx/10/ (I also made sure your inner table was closed)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the closing tag error :) I am still getting an alert with the '0' with this code. I added a clarification to the OP that I don't want anything to happen when I click on the excluded row.